# How to find the center point of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am detecting green color using PIL and numpy. Since the code finds lots of green pixels even in non-green area. Thus, I am finding the nearest value of them to a value that I specified, I get a 3 matching points that provides a (1512L, 3L) matrix. Code is below. As a result, I want to plot this matrix on the original image to see the location. How can I do that ? Sample image is also below.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image and make RGB and HSV versions
RGBim = Image.open("AdjustedNewMaze3.jpg").convert('RGB')
HSVim = RGBim.convert('HSV')

# Make numpy versions
RGBna = np.array(RGBim)
HSVna = np.array(HSVim)

# Extract Hue
H = HSVna[:,:,0]

# Find all green pixels, i.e. where 100 < Hue < 140
lo,hi = 100,140
# Rescale to 0-255, rather than 0-360 because we are using uint8
lo = int((lo * 255) / 360)
hi = int((hi * 255) / 360)
green = np.where((H>lo) & (H<hi))

# Make all green pixels black in original image
RGBna[green] = [0,0,0]

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

value = 120

green = find_nearest(RGBna, value)
average = np.average(green)
print(green)

count = green[0].size
print("Pixels matched: {}".format(count))
Image.fromarray(green).save('resultgreen.png')
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you are using JPEG format to save your images and losing quality which you were already lacking at the start... Are you using a Raspberry Pi? Can you acquire at higher quality setting or as raw RGB? Can you save intermediate results of your processing as PNG or NetPBM PPM files? Try installing **ImageMagick** and separating out the Hue, Saturation and Lightness and look at the Hue image (`chan-0.png`) and you will see what I mean `magick AdjustedNewMaze3.jpg -colorspace hsl -separate chan-%d.png`

Comment: I have also png format of this image. When I use it, There is found more and more green points than the actual green area. Also, cotrast of the first image in post is enhanced. So it is not raw. As for raw RGB image, I used it also. it also works bad. Also,  I am using Logitech c930e which is actually high quality. 
What do you mean about HSV ? I couldn't figure out much. @MarkSetchell

Comment: If you start with JPEG, or use JPEG for saving intermediate results when image processing, the quality deteriorates quite badly. If you run the **ImageMagick** command in my previous comment you will get this image where the Hue channel is on the left, Saturation in the middle and Lightness on the right. http://thesetchells.com/result.png Hopefully you can see that JPEG has made a mess of the Hue on the left and identifying anything in there is going to be tough. Maybe notice how the Red shows up as nicely saturated in the central frame.

Comment: You are definetely right. Because I could not run `magick AdjustedNewMaze3.jpg -colorspace hsl -separate chan-%d.png`so that I could not compare as you did although I installed into anaconda and import ImageMagic in the code. I would like to try this code with the PNG format of the same image. @MarkSetchell

Comment: The **ImageMagick** command is not related to Python or Anaconda. It is just run from Terminal, or shell (or CMD.EXE on Windows).

Comment: my ignorance, sorry. But even after deciding that png is better to process, I need to plot numpy matrix